# Superset installation keep on time-out (WSL 2)

Tags: kubernetes-helm, apache-superset

I'm trying to deploy Superset into my k3d cluster. First I create my k3d cluster, then I use helm to install the superset as follow:
`helm repo add superset https://apache.github.io/superset`

`helm search repo superset`

Configure some value (e.g., connection) in the values.yaml, I use the default postgre and commented the postgre db_host

Installation: `helm upgrade --install --debug --values values.yaml superset superset/superset`

But it fails without giving me much clue to work on:

```
    helm upgrade --install --debug --values values.yaml superset superset/superset
history.go:56: [debug] getting history for release superset
Release "superset" does not exist. Installing it now.
install.go:200: [debug] Original chart version: ""
install.go:217: [debug] CHART PATH: /home/silvina/.cache/helm/repository/superset-0.10.8.tgz

client.go:134: [debug] creating 16 resource(s)
client.go:478: [debug] Starting delete for "superset-init-db" Job
client.go:134: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:706: [debug] Watching for changes to Job superset-init-db with timeout of 5m0s
client.go:734: [debug] Add/Modify event for superset-init-db: ADDED
client.go:773: [debug] superset-init-db: Jobs active: 0, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:734: [debug] Add/Modify event for superset-init-db: MODIFIED
client.go:773: [debug] superset-init-db: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
Error: failed post-install: 1 error occurred:
        * timed out waiting for the condition


helm.go:84: [debug] failed post-install: 1 error occurred:
        * timed out waiting for the condition
```

Did I set the value wrongly? Or do I miss some configuration?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/25416) for Apache Superset's helm chart `0.10.8`. Either use Superset helm chart `0.10.7` or wait for the [fix to be merged](https://github.com/apache/superset/pull/25373).

Comment: Hey Sebastian, 
Can you please tell me how to install Superset helm chart 0.10.7 in details.
Thanks

Comment: I'm already using latest version of superset and helm, still having this issue.